# C++ : Avoid lot of boolean variable for multiple verification conditions in trading app

Tags: c++, trading

i am a junior dev in trading app... we have a order refresh verification unit. It has to verify order confirmation from exchange. We send a bunch of different request in bulk ( NEW, MODIFY, CANCEL ) to exchange... Verification has to happen for max N times with each T intervals for all orders. if verification successful for all the order before N retry then fine.. otherwise we need to indicate as verification unsuccessfull. i hv done a basic coding done in very urgent like below

```
for( N times )
{
   for_each ( sent_request_order )   // SENT
   {
       1) get all the  refreshed order from DB or shared mem i.e REFRESHED
       2) find current sent order in REFRESHED 

       if( not_found )
            not refreshed from exchange, continue to next order

       if( found )

       case NEW :    //check for new status, mark verification done
       case MODIFY : //check for modified status.. 
                     //if not mark pending, go to next order, 
                     //revisit the same after T time
       case CANCEL : //check for cancelled status.. 
                     //if not mark pending, go to next order, 
                     //revisit the same after T time
   }

   if( all_verified )
       exit from verification.

   wait ( T sec )

}
```

order_verification_pending, order_verification_done,  order_visited, order_not_visited, all_verified, all_not_verified ... lot of boolean flags used for indication..

is there any better approach for doing this.... splitting responsibilities across the classes......????

i know this is not a general question.... but still flags are making me tidious to handle...

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm looks workable. Implement it.

Do not try to optimize your code before you got it working. Once you have a working version running, nevermind how ugly, *then* you look at ways & means to optimize. Chances are good that you will then find a way to handle the flags that gives you so much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You talk about "order_verification_pending, order_verification_done, order_visited, order_not_visited, all_verified, all_not_verified"... but that seems to double the number of booleans, for example: if you have `order_visited` then you don't need order_not_visited... it is just "`!order_visited`".  When there are more than two states involved, use an `enum` instead of a lot of complicated, overlapping booleans.  For example, if verification might be pending, done, failed etc. but these are all mutually exclusive, then store the single current state in that `enum`.

It's more elegant to have a set of pending operations, and remove elements from that set until the set is empty or the whole verification times out.  That way, you're not checking operations you already found succeeded.